# Setting [Authorize] attribute on signalr hub class works only when connecting to the hub and not before each method on the hub (ASP.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, signalr-hub

I'm trying to add authentication to my signalR hub but it works only for the 'negotiate' method and not for every request sent to the hub.

In `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureService` I added :

```
// Authentication
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters(authSettings.PublicKey);
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs")))
                    {
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
        });
```

In the `Configure` method I added:

```
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"), config => config.UseAuthentication());
```

And added the `[Authorize]` attribute on the hub class:

```
[Authorize]
public class ProtocolMethodsHub : Hub<IProtocolMethodsHub>, IProtocolMethodsHub {}
```

I set a breakpoint in the `OnMessageReceived` but it is called only when connecting to signalR and not for each request the is sent through the websocket .

Is there a way to authenticate/authorize each request to the hub?

Answer (score 0):

It feels wrong to per request add/remove middleware like this:

```
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"), config => config.UseAuthentication());
```

You can better handle that in the authorization part of the system. AddJwtBearer does not care if the incoing request contains a token or not. Just that, if thr request contains a token, then it should be valid. AddJwtBearer does care about what you are allowed to do, that job is the authorization part. All AddJwtBearer wants to do is to create a User object based on the incoming token.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR uses [different transports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0#transports) under the hood and each transport can behave a bit differently. For example, if it is using Websocket transport, you are creating a persistent connection between the server and the client and all of the requests go through this connection (which is different than normal HTTP requests) so it only checks the JWT validity during the establishment of the connection. For other transports, the checks happen more often but they still happen only when you are establishing the client connection to the server. In other words, you have already checked the JWT and you know it is valid when the requests start coming in, and SignalR does not double-check the JWT. If you would like to control the authorization and access by the JWT, you might want to either:

1. Use different hubs with different levels of access.
2. In your SignalR hub check the claims of the token to see if the user has access to what they are doing.

---

UPDATE: So after reading the comments, and I realized that you are looking to figure out what to do when a JWT is expired but the connection is still active. This would only be an issue for Websocket transport since it keeps the persistent connection. I do not believe there is a built-in way to handle this, so I can think of 2 different approaches:

1. When creating the JWT, include a timestamp claim in the JWT so you can access it every time there is a request in your SignalR hub, if the timestamp is expired just close the connection and force the connection to create a new JWT (assuming you have reconnection logic in your client). Using this approach you can also do more complex checks, in addition to the timestamp, to make sure the JWT is still valid.
2. In your client code have a schedule to automatically close and re-open the connection every few minutes. This can cause issues if you are trying to minimize the amount of time that the connection is interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. We use WebSockets, but how can we handle an expired token during the session ?

Comment: Handling the actual JWT is going to be dependent on your client. If you are using the .NET client you will need to do something like: `new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(hubUrl, connectionOptions =>
                {
                    connectionOptions.AccessTokenProvider = // Your access token provider
                }).Build();`
To handle retrieval, storage, and generation of JWT on your client.

Comment: After re-reading your comment I think I might know what you are asking. Are you asking what to do when a JWT is expired but the connection is still active? Basically how to interrupt the connection and ask the client to get a new JWT?

Comment: Exactly. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: @user1977367 I updated the answer since it didn't fit here. I hope it is helpful.